# reactJS not applying styles (.less files)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to search on the topic but it seems that I might be using the wrong terms as I cannot find any information....

I am trying to get this package to work..(https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment)

I have succeeded in getting the calendar to work, it saves the date, but it will not switch to the time tab and it also does not style correctly, even though I have imported the .less files into my react component.. the file looks like this...

```
require('input-moment/src/less/input-moment.less')

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import moment from 'moment';
import InputMoment from 'input-moment';

class Date extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {m: moment()}
  }

  handleChange(m) {
    this.setState({ m });
  }

  handleSave() {
    console.log('saved', this.state.m.format('llll'));
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <InputMoment
          moment={this.state.m}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSave={this.handleSave}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

and yet my component looks like this...

[image: InputMoment]

Can you see any obvious reason as to why the component will not style correctly like the example on github...(http://wangzuo.github.io/input-moment/)

Comment: this line shouldn't be here : require('input-moment/src/less/input-moment.less'). input-moment/src doesn't even exist ! The less file is already included by the package creator. The documentation on input-moment is, to say the least, very unclear....

Comment: ok. I still have the same problem without that line...any ideas?

Comment: When reading the "exemple" provided by the creator, it seems that actually the less file isn't included in the package (my mistake). I suggest you duplicate this .less file in your project, and then link it : if you place it in the same folder as your Date component, it will be import './input-moment.less'; (directly after all your other imports)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably aren't getting the styles provided by the package. If you used npm to install the package, then your import statement could look like this:

`require('input-moment/dist/input-moment.css')`

Also, compare your App.css to the CSS used by the package author in the example, which can be found at https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/blob/master/example/app.less, source is repeated below

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.app {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding: 0 20px;

  .input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  input {
    padding: 7px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Yeah, I was in the process of editing that. It's fixed now.

Comment: the actual import path was 'input-moment/dist/input-moment.css'... if you can edit your answer for others that would be great. Is css always to be imported over the less files?

Comment: Edited. Does that look right now? I'm don't know if there are best practices around how to import CSS from a package. Would like to know myself ;-)